# rviz pre-configured lauch file for Navigation stack

Tags: navigation, rviz, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have or know where to find an rviz configuration file that is already setup for the common topics and tf's used in the navigation stack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225787/rviz-pre-configured-lauch-file-for-navigation-stack/) by [trips323](https://answers.ros.org/users/24982/trips323/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `navigation_stage` package (part of the `navigation_tutorials` repository) has a `.rviz` file you could use:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/navigation_stage

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trips323](https://answers.ros.org/users/24982/trips323/) on 2016-02-04**:
Perfect! thanks